# Is Biden more apt to press for harder terms and/or the renegotiation of the post-Brexit UK–US trade deal if he wins the Presidency?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, brexit, trade, joe-biden

I was listening to LBC earlier when I noted both [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53620/could-the-us-space-force-be-dissolved-when-trump-is-gone) and the statement on air regarding Brexit policies and Trump. In essence, Trump has clearly come out as a pro-Brexit person and promised 'a good deal' for Johnson's Britain though this [in itself is questionable](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2019/09/02/trump-has-lot-say-about-brexit-do-brits-listen/) given his 'America first' policies and [the reported difficulties](https://www.ft.com/content/03ee5fc6-42d7-11ea-a43a-c4b328d9061c) British trade negotiators have described, e.g. on the chlorinated chicken issue which by now Johnson seems to have [thrown into the wind](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2020/jun/06/uk-accused-u-turn-animal-welfare-us-trade-talks).

In light of this, and perhaps Trump's recent difficulties at home, I was wondering what Biden has been considering with respect to the US–UK trade deal.

This doesn't seem to be a very popular question yet, but there are suggestions that even Trump's negotiated deal might not be 'hard' enough for Biden: [this article](https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/1250158/brexit-news-eu-us-trade-talks-deal-joe-biden-super-tuesday-chlorinated-chicken-spt) and [this one](https://www.ucdclinton.ie/commentary-content/a-joe-biden-presidency-and-congress-may-block-us-uk-post-brexit-trade-deal). Yet, these are relatively old sayings from 2016.

**Has Biden recently stated any new positions on what he considers acceptable/unacceptable in a US–UK trade deal? Are there any known red lines beyond Trump's that would cause him to scupper any deals Trump may have previously made?**

Comment: Might be better to ask specifically about Biden's stated/official position (if any) on this, as I think the question is a bit speculative as is otherwise. There's been a lot of change in partisan opinions on "free trade" since 2016, so it's hard to speculate on positions based purely on party association. Also, Biden just clenched the nomination a few days ago, so barring something really unprecedented, the presidential candidates will be Trump and Biden

Comment: @divibisan: Thanks & fair enough; edit affected as recommended. I was unsure if the parties in general have "trade policy positions" which I figured they might but I removed that part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brexit negotiation has taken a back seat to other priorities nearly the world-over since the UK went through with Brexit without any promises or guarantees from any individual country or coalition. The UK has lost nearly all bargaining power in its relationships, such that when it does seek out trade deals, it will be on the other country's timeline and following the other country's rules.

As for the US specifically? Neither candidate is going to be significantly better economically for the UK. Given the instability and lawlessness going on internally, both candidates are focusing on those issues rather than ones abroad. Trump is unlikely to give a deal to Johnson when he can just as easily not do so, while Biden was strongly against Brexit due to the fact that it significantly diminished US power in Europe. Neither are a likely ally in the near future.

Comment: I can see Trump signing a trade deal when he needs a diversion from yet another domestic problem. He knows it will shift press attention, it fits his self-proclaimed deal-maker personality, and he can present it as fulfilling an earlier promise. "Best trade deal ever." I agree Trump won't make a deal in the interest of the country.

Answer (score 1):

The Democrats have [previously said](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-northern-ireland-47979214) that they would not do a trade deal if the Irish border was not resolved. Given that there seems to be little prospect of resolving it at the moment with the UK backtracking on the Withdrawal Agreement that could cause any future Democrat president less inclined to do a deal.

Comment: Interesting! I wasn't aware that anything that specific had been said. Do you have a source for that so I can get additional context?

Comment: @divibisan this is possibly just referring to the UCD Clinton Institute article linked at the end of the question- I'm not aware of any recent statement from Biden on this.

Comment: @divibisan It may also be referring to Nancy Pelosi's stated position. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-northern-ireland-47979214

Comment: The Congressional Irish Caucus has said they would oppose any trade deal if there were issues with the Irish border. Given the relative power of this caucus, it is unlikely any President could push through a trade deal until the border issues are resolved